# math operators cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'string'

Tags: c#

I have an error on equals button.

```
private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblShowOp.Text = "";
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "+":
            tb1.Text = (results + Double.Parse(tb1.Text).ToString());
            break;
        case "-":
            // operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double and string'
            tb1.Text = (results - Double.Parse(tb1.Text).ToString());
            break;
        case "*":
            // operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double and string'
            tb1.Text = (results * Double.Parse(tb1.Text).ToString());
            break;
        case "/":
            // operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double and string'
            tb1.Text = (results / Double.Parse(tb1.Text).ToString());
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper on the last part. there is a comment there that shows the error.

Comment: @Sayse the error on the last part is operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double and string'

Comment: You should try to create an [mcve] when asking a question as well as showing your own efforts into fixing it.

Comment: @Sayse sorry sir. Noted! i just joined here last week. i hope you understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Double.Parse(tb1.Text).ToString()` will parse to a number and then convert back to a string.

Per the error message, you can't add a number to a string (or multiply, subtract etc).

You have your brackets in the wrong place. Change from this:

```
tb1.Text = (results + Double.Parse(tb1.Text).ToString());
```

To this:

```
tb1.Text = (results + Double.Parse(tb1.Text)).ToString();
```

And similarly for each of the others.